# Filtering based on multiple categories

Tags: sql, oracle

My search to filter based on multiple categories listed below, for any records that fall in categories A-F but do not have more than 1 item from the same category. I will try to explain with an example.

```
A Bread
B Apple 
C Strawberry OR Blueberry OR Raspberry
D Watermelon OR Muskmelon OR Honeydew
E Papaya
F Oranges OR Peaches OR Nectarines



T1:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7

T2:
ID  Category
1   Bread
2   Apple 
2   Strawberry 
3   Blueberry 
3   Raspberry
4   Watermelon 
5   Muskmelon 
5   Honeydew
4   Papaya
2  Oranges 
1  Peaches 
5  Nectarines
```

In the above scenario, my search is to return:

```
1 Bread,Peaches
2 Apple,Strawberry, Oranges
4 Watermelon,Papaya
```

3 and 5 are not to be returned as they have items from the same category -

```
#3: Blueberry and Raspberry
#5: Muskmelon, Honeydew and Nectarines
```

Comment: What is supposed to be in T1?

Comment: T1 is a parent table, only joins with T2 on the IDs.

Comment: OK, so what have you tried?

Comment: I am not sure which way to go hence the question.

Comment: So where do Categories A-F come from?

Comment: its not in the database, it is the requirement provided based on the data

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need a table -- call it `CATEGORY_GROUPS ( category, category_group )` -- that relates this information from your post:

> ```
> A Bread
> B Apple 
> C Strawberry OR Blueberry OR Raspberry
> D Watermelon OR Muskmelon OR Honeydew
> E Papaya
> F Oranges OR Peaches OR Nectarines
> ```

Where, for example, 'Bread' would be the category and 'A' would be the category group.

Then, you join `t1`, `t2`, and `category_groups` together in a query so you have every item, its category and its category group. Then group by the `id`.

The key part is how to restrict the items that have duplicates.  If there are duplicates, then the number of distinct category groups will be less than the number of categories.  So, you can use that condition in your `HAVING` clause to get what you want.

Like this should work:

```
SELECT t1.id, listagg(t2.category,',') within group ( order by category )
FROM  t1 inner join t2 on t2.id = t1.id
inner join category_groups cg on cg.category = t2.category
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cg.category_group) < COUNT(DISTINCT t2.category)
```